# Women not allowed during burial

Tags: death, funeral

Why women are not allowed to attend the burial of someone?

If a person dies, then he can be a father or brother of a woman, then doesn't she have the right to attend the burial procession?

Answer (score 0):

According to various madhabs women are discouraged from accompanying the funeral and from visiting graves. This is based on the ahadith:

> أن رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم لعن زوارات القبور
>
> The Messenger of Allah ﷺ cursed the women who visit the graves.
>
> <sup>— [Jami at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:1056)</sup>

> نهينا عن اتباع الجنائز، ولم يعزم علينا‏
>
> We were forbidden to accompany funeral processions but not strictly / (or) it was not made obligatory on us.
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:1278)</sup>

> قال ‏‏ لعلك بلغت معهم الكدى ‏‏ ‏.‏ قالت معاذ الله أن أكون بلغتها وقد سمعتك تذكر في ذلك ما تذكر
>
> The Prophet ﷺ said: 'Perhaps you went with them to Al-Kuda? (graveyard)"
>
> Fatimah said: 'Allah forbid that I should go there. I heard what you said about that.'
>
> <sup>— [Nasai](https://sunnah.com/nasai:1880)</sup>

As for the reason or wisdom behind it, some scholars have stated that it is because usually grieving women wail or say reprehensible things etc. And the prohibition is to prevent making such a spectacle. Further the requirements such as segregation and hijab are difficult to observe during the burial.

Comment: As per https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:1056 , is it not permissible for women to even visit graves after burial as well? I understand why women are not allowed to attend the burial procession because of the reasons you wrote but what about visiting the graves after the burial?

Comment: https://islamqa.info/en/answers/127/